# accessibility: adding label to custom input element in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, accessibility

We have some custom components which can be used for user input (`CustomSelect`, `SegmentedControl`, `CustomCheckbox`, etc).

In some cases, these internally use the semantic html tag like `radiogroup` or `select`, but in some cases, the markup is completely written using `div` and `span` elements and accessibility is provided using aria attributes. For such implementations, is there a way to associate a `label` element to them, to make them behave like native form inputs wrt label behaviour, or better, is there a way to get them treated like native form inputs?

Things that come to mind:

- use a visually hidden html form element which somehow wraps the custom, and somehow hide its semantics.
- fieldset and legend might make sense in some cases
- using javascript to imitate label functionality

Are there any existing patterns for this?

Comment: CAn you explain why aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby wouldn't suit your needs ? Thank you.

Comment: because they are not for the visual user. The mouse user can't click on them to focus on the custom input (or to trigger the default behaviour of the custom input)

Comment: Well you always will need javascript when you don't use semantic HTML. So just use semantic HTML, that's why its there.

Comment: Sure, we are using semantic html wherever it makes sense, but html alone does not provide all the different input types or complex widgets for that matter. consider the menubutton pattern for example. HTML does not have a native menu implementation which complies with this. https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-actions.html .You can definitely use some semantic element to workaround these limitations in some cases, but that is not always enough

Answer (score 4):

You need to do three things:

1. Visually code it so that the label looks like it's associated with your custom element, typically because the label is to the left and the element is to the right (in LTR languages).
2. Programmatically associate the label with the element by using `aria-labelledby`.
3. Add javascript so that mouse clicking on the label moves the focus to the element.

Note that you can use a real `<label>` element but it would mainly be for more readable code, so it's easy to spot the label associated with the element.  You most likely (*) **cannot** use the `for` attribute of the `<label>` element because the ID specified must be of a "[labelable element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label)", which is defined as:

- button
- input
- meter
- output
- progress
- select
- textarea

(*) You **can** use the `for` attribute if you have a custom element with a `form-associated` attribute of *true*.  A `<label>` can be used on a "[form-associated custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#form-associated-custom-element)"

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-face-example.

I have not created a custom form element before but the doc sounds like a real `<label for="ID">` can be used with it, in which case you don't need `aria-labelledby` or javascript.